# Links dentro da página não abre nem funciona

Tags: php, javascript, html, seo

Galera, eu subi uma pagina no site do cliente, a página está ok, mas os links não funcionam, quando clicam, já mudei o htaccess do site, coloquei até um link no site que vai direto pro site do google, mas mesmo assim não funciona.

O site é esse http://biliato.com.br/informacoes/mapa-do-site

Alguém pode me dar uma luz, do que pode ser ?

Comment: Cara, é algum código JavaScript que está causando isso você deve ter feito algo errado(Tipo está certo, mas não é o que você queria) se você abrir as ferramentas de desenvolvedor e ir em settings/Disable JavaScript e depois atualizar a página verá que todos os links dá página voltam a funcionar normalmente, mas porque ? ainda não sei, mas de uma olhada no JavaScript, sei lá, você pode ter usado um preventDefault() nos link, não sei, mas de uma olhada no JavaScript.

Comment: É realmente cara, fiz  pela ferramenta de desenvolvedor e os links funcionaram, vou dar uma olhada no meu js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A culpa é desse código js em sua página:

```
$(function() {
  $('a').on('click', function() {
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Foi isso mesmo cara, mto obrigado.